# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 as dual boot: Black Screen

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, windows-10

I am trying to set up a dual boot of Ubunutu 16.04 64 bit along side my windows 10 installation. I downloaded a ubunutu 64 bit 16.06 ISO and made a bootable USB drive. I also created a partition and changed the BIOS so that the USB has priority.

When I start up my computer, my screen is off, there is no input and nothing seems to be happening.
I managed to get it working with ubunutu 14 32 bit but just with 16.04 this happens.
Any suggestions or fixes?
Thanks.

Comment: Is system UEFI or BIOS? Only 64 bit works with BIOS. And what brand/model system and what video card? If nVidia or AMD, you may need nomodeset. http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it And if AMD version makes a difference on what driver works at all.

Comment: My system is BIOS. I have an intel i7 processor with an NVIDIA card. I can't set nomodeset because I don't even get the purple screen, it's just nothing happens and my screen is black / off because there is nothing.

Comment: If you have an i7 processor then it is UEFI but can boot in CSM - or BIOS emulation. Are you getting the assesiblity icons at bottom of screen for a few seconds. That is BIOS and you have to press the famous "any" key to get screen to add nomodeset with f6. If UEFI boot you should get grub menu. Screens shown in link above. Some turn off use of video card and use internal Intel video to install, then add nVidia driver and re-enable nVidia card. What brand/model system or motherboard.